# How can I disable a network interface permanently in Debian 10?

Tags: network-interface

I reckon there's a similar question on this site ( [How to permanently disable a network interface?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/111256/how-to-permanently-disable-a-network-interface) ), but the answers were mainly for Ubuntu and the methods described in there didn't help.

I'm trying to bring down a enp1s0f2 interface, but it keeps coming back on reboot.

I've tried the commands "ifconfig (interface) down", "ifdown (interface)", and editing /etc/network/interfaces to add the following lines:

"iface (interface) inet manual" and
"iface (interface) inet6 manual"

Supposedly so that NetworkManager or whatever else is managing it, doesn't load it on startup, but to no avail.

How can I permanently disable this interface on Debian?

Is there a clean method that doesn't involve disabling all device systemctl services one by one? It would be a shame if at any point I needed the interface again that I had to remember all services involved and re-enable them again, plus, there must be a simpler straight method, right?

Answer (score 6):

You can tell NetworkManager to ignore the interface, as documented in the keyfile section of [NetworkManager.conf](https://developer.gnome.org/NetworkManager/stable/NetworkManager.conf.html#id-1.2.3.8):

> **keyfile section**
>
> This section contains keyfile-plugin-specific options, and is normally
> only used when you are not using any other distro-specific plugin.
>
> [...]
>
> `unmanaged-devices`
>
> Set devices that should be ignored by NetworkManager.
>
> See [the section called “Device List Format”](https://developer.gnome.org/NetworkManager/stable/NetworkManager.conf.html#device-spec) for the syntax how to
> specify a device.
>
> Example:
>
> ```
> unmanaged-devices=interface-name:em4
> unmanaged-devices=mac:00:22:68:1c:59:b1;mac:00:1E:65:30:D1:C4;interface-name:eth2
> ```

Add a file in `/etc/NetworkManager/conf.d` called for example `local-ignore-enp1s0f2.conf` with this additional content:

```
[keyfile]
unmanaged-devices=interface-name:enp1s0f2
```

You might still have to delete an entry it already created with something like:

```
nmcli connection show
```

and once the name identified:

```
nmcli connection delete id 'some unwanted connection'
ip link set enp1s0f2 down
```

Then reload the configuration:

```
nmcli connection reload
```

or:

```
systemctl reload network-manager
```

If you want to check it worked without rebooting, here's a trick using a network namespace (which could also have been used instead in some script probably in *udev* to make the interface automatically "disappear"):

```
ip netns add hiddenplace
ip link set enp1s0f2 netns hiddenplace
```

Now remove the namespace which will bring back the interface and trigger any auto-detection:

```
ip netns delete hiddenplace
```

Comment: I tried this method but apparently something is raising it up at boot time, when I reboot it says "Raise network interfaces", then it enables it, I'm not sure if it has to do with ifupdown (it's set to not managed on /etc/network/interfaces) or if some startup script brings it up

Answer (score 0):

You can set both its IPv4 and IPv6 addresses to "Disabled" in NetworkManager which will essentially disable the interface.

Then there's this "Connect automatically with Priority" which can unchecked - which probably does the same.