# How to completely disable network interfaces in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: networking, network-interface, devices

On my Ubuntu 16.04 server, I need to disable the onboard NIC for troubleshooting before upgrading to 22.04. It's important that the entire NIC no longer shows up as a network controller in my device at all.

**Basically what I want is to only keep my local loopback device for a working 127.0.0.1 and get rid of ALL other network controllers.**

Things I've tried:

- I've tried the BIOS but there's no configurable network controller in there (Dell desktop machine).
- I've tried setting the interface to 'manual' and not configuring it in `/etc/network/interfaces`, but it's not working.
- I've tried the suggested solutions involving 'udev' and 'systemd' at [How to permanently disable a network interface?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/111256/how-to-permanently-disable-a-network-interface) but it keeps coming back somehow.

The damn thing keeps coming back...

Comment: Can you give us a few more details? Is this a laptop? A desktop? Are you talking about a wired connection or wireless? What exactly do you want to test? Is it enough that the NIC doesn't connect or does it need to be invisible to the rest of the system? Or maybe it's OK to be visible but it needs to be disabled? The more detail you give, the better your chances of getting useful answers.

Comment: Instead of adding your own Q&A, when you’d already found another (largely equivalent) question with answers that didn’t work for you, why not add your answer there?

Comment: @terdon I updated my question, thanks for the comment

Comment: @StephenKitt My approach and solution differed; sharing my journey on a new thread might help others and boosts searchability. It would have been lost in the noise. At least this solution works for multiple systems and is easily reversible by deleting the blacklist entry, re-running `update-initramfs -u` and rebooting.

Comment: @StephenKitt I have updated the question to better reflect my situation which I should have done beforehand. It's been a long day; thank you for pointing this out; as a response to my changing question I've also changed my answer to become even better. Thanks for your time!

Answer (score -1):

Ok, I found a solution myself that seems to do exactly what I want.

I can confirm it works on Ubuntu 16.04 on a system with an onboard NIC and Wi-Fi controller, however I haven't tested it for other distributions, but a quick glance at the documentation suggests that it should also work for other distributions, but don't take my word for it; do your own research in the documentation to verify.

The reason I am using this solution is because it is easily reversible once I'm done with the troubleshooting I need to do. I basically just want to get rid of all network controllers on the system and only keep my loopback device for a working 127.0.0.1.

## Disabling all network drivers entirely

To disable network interfaces on an Ubuntu 16.04 server, you can use the following oneliner to blacklist the network modules. This will prevent the kernel from loading the modules, effectively disabling the interfaces. Here's the oneliner and a breakdown of its steps:

### Command line oneliner

```
modules=$(lspci -k | grep -iE 'network|ethernet|wi-fi|bluetooth|wireless|lan|wlan' --after=3 | grep modules | awk '{print $3}'); for module in $(echo "$modules" | tr ' ' '\n'); do if ! grep -q -w "blacklist $module" /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf; then echo "blacklist $module" | tee -a /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf; else echo "Already blacklisted: $module. Skipping."; fi; done; update-initramfs -u && echo Done! Reboot your system to finalize the changes.
```

### Breakdown

The oneliner consists of several commands combined using shell constructs:

1. `modules=$(lspci -k | grep -iE 'network|ethernet|wi-fi|bluetooth|wireless|lan|wlan' --after=3 | grep modules | awk '{print $3}')`: This command retrieves a list of relevant network modules and saves it in the `modules` variable.
2. `for module in $(echo "$modules" | tr ' ' '\n'); do ...; done`: This is a loop that iterates over each module in the `modules` variable.
3. `if ! grep -q -w "blacklist $module" /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf; then ...; else ...; fi`: This is an if-else construct that checks if the module is already blacklisted in the configuration file.
4. `echo "blacklist $module" | tee -a /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf`: If the module is not blacklisted, this command appends a new blacklist entry to the configuration file.
5. `echo "Already blacklisted: $module. Skipping."`: If the module is already blacklisted, this command prints a message indicating so.
6. `update-initramfs -u && echo`: After processing all modules, this command updates the initramfs and shows the message about rebooting.

### Manual alternative

If for some reason the oneliner doesn't work or you want to closely follow what's going on, you can follow these manual steps:

1. Run `lspci -k` to list all devices and their respective kernel modules. Identify the modules related to network controllers by running: `lspci -k | grep -iE 'network|ethernet|wi-fi|bluetooth|wireless|lan|wlan' --after=3 | grep modules | awk '{print $3}'`.
2. Open `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf` with your favorite text editor, e.g., `sudo nano /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf`.
3. For each module you want to blacklist, add a new line at the end of the file: `blacklist MODULE_NAME`, replacing `MODULE_NAME` with the actual module name.
4. Save and close the file.
5. Update the initramfs by running `sudo update-initramfs -u`.
6. Reboot your system: `sudo reboot`.

To revert this, simply comment or remove the newly created 'blacklist' entries you just made, and run step 5 and 6.

Hopefully this helps anyone out there looking for the same solution.

Comment: Note that this will disable all network interfaces managed by the excluded module, not just the interface you were initially interested in. https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/467085/86440 seems more generally applicable — did it not work for you?

Comment: "I'll also post it to other questions I find" – If an answer can answer two questions then the questions are probably duplicates and one of them should be closed. Specifically, if your answer answers the [linked question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/111256/108618) then the right thing to do was to post it there in the first place and not to create a duplicate question.

Comment: @StephenKitt the oneliner checks for that and shows an error if you have more than one result

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski I disagree; my exact thought process to arrive at the answer was not identical and neither were my solutions. Additionally, I wanted to maximize the chances of people discovering the solution by presenting my initial situation first.

Comment: @HenryvanMegen apologies, so it does. You didn’t answer my question… Note too that this doesn’t work for me on a ThinkPad P1Gen3 running RHEL 8.

Comment: @HenryvanMegen “my exact thought process to arrive at the answer was not identical and neither were my solutions” — if everyone reasoned like that, every single question here that gets multiple answers would be turned into multiple Qs&As. That’s not how this site works.

Comment: If you wanted our answers because the answers under the other question don't work for you and you needed help, [we would understand](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4231/108618). But you knew your answer before posting the new question, you posted the answer with the question. Worse, you're planning to post it wherever it fits. [This is officially not right](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5847/108618). Answering the other question was the best choice.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski I still think this question and solution is relevant because that question is about a wireless controller on a desktop version of Ubuntu with an entirely different network system from the one on Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: Well, I won't keep arguing then. Note I started from criticizing "I'll also post it to other questions I find". This plan is still [wrong](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5854/108618).

Comment: This is really a pretty bad solution, as it disables a driver, hence a whole family of network cards that might be in your system, and not just a single interface, which is what you set out to do. It would be a worthy "also, you can do… with the following downsides" answer to the existing question.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski I agree.. I have removed those double-posts. But what about referencing this situation on similar but not the same situations? Mine is really different from the situation described in the other question. I don't care about internet points, I just want this solution to help someone else struggling with the same issue.

Comment: Posting a link (even in comments) is enough to link questions to each other. Both questions are already linked (see the "Linked" section in the right column). A person studying the list of questions linked to the other question will easily find your question. If you emphasize in the title what's unique in your question, a person with similar problem will be able to consciously pick your question from the list to check before other links.

Comment: Yeah, sorry about this @HenryvanMegen. I mean, you have clearly put in a lot of effort, and even took the time to post your solution to help future users (thank you, by the way, that is always appreciated!) and here we are giving you trouble about where you posted it on. Unfortunately, we're kind of obsessive about that here, and with good reason: we want these sites to be better organized than the traditional forums which is why we put so much effort into cleanup.

Comment: So, as the others told you, could you please either post this as an answer to the other question or edit your question to clarify why this issue is different from that discussed in the other question? Perhaps by explaining exactly what you need here and whether it is disabling networking, or disabling a specific card, or just blocking the card from connecting?

Comment: @terdon No problem, I fully understand.. Quality over Quantity is something I agree with. I have updated my original question and answer to even better reflect my situation as I wanted to get rid of ALL NIC's on the system. This is somewhat of a unique situation, I know, but hey.. at least now it doesn't closely resemble the other questions on here anymore, effectively turning it into more unique content.. I say win:win for all.. without the comments here, this wouldn't have happened. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski I took your comments and ran with it; in doing so the question got even better descriptive of my situation and so did my solution for it. Thanks for your time.

Comment: @StephenKitt thank you for your initial comments; you were one of the people pushing me to clarify my situation and initial question even better, resulting in an even better solution and answer here in the process. Thank you for your time!

Comment: @MarcusMüller I'm sorry.. I wasn't clear in my initial question and in my initial answer. I've updated it to reflect my situation. Thank you for pointing out what I already knew but didn't realize I hadn't mentioned. Much appreciated :)